# How to automate VMs creatiion/setup process

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am creating some VMs in Azure using Azure CLI. These VMs require different setups. For example, one machine needs to be set up as a domain controller and therefore its setup includes activities such as creating domain users, etc. While the activities for other VMs include things like joining the domain, set up fire share, etc. Currently, any activity on the individual VMs is performed manually. However, I would like to automate that process starting from creating the VMs and then performing setup on individual VM. What could be the best way of doing it? Can this type of setup on individual VMs be performed remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look at the Azure **Desired State Configuration (DSC)** extension.  DSC is a declarative platform used for configuration, deployment, and management of systems. It consists of three primary components:

- Configurations are declarative PowerShell scripts which define and
  configure instances of resources. Upon running the configuration, DSC
  (and the resources being called by the configuration) will simply
  "make it so", ensuring that the system exists in the state laid out
  by the configuration. DSC configurations are also idempotent: the
  Local Configuration Manager (LCM) will continue to ensure that
  machines are configured in whatever state the configuration declares.
- Resources are the "make it so" part of DSC. They contain the code
  that put and keep the target of a configuration in the specified
  state. Resources reside in PowerShell modules and can be written to
  model something as generic as a file or a Windows process, or as
  specific as an IIS server or a VM running in Azure.
- The Local
  Configuration Manager (LCM) is the engine by which DSC facilitates
  the interaction between resources and configurations. The LCM
  regularly polls the system using the control flow implemented by
  resources to ensure that the state defined by a configuration is
  maintained. If the system is out of state, the LCM makes calls to the
  code in resources to "make it so" according to the configuration.

An example **Azure ARM template** that uses DSC to stand up a domain controller can be seen here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/active-directory-new-domain

**Further Reading**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/overview/overview?view=powershell-7.1